# convert field number to date on kibana, elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I've a field number on Elasticsearch via Kibana.

This is an example field:

```
"insert.datePeticio:1,546,185,770,733"
```

I need to convert this field to date, for visualize purpose.

How can I parse it to date mode?

Answer (score 14):

As far as I understand, you have an integer field on Elasticsearch that stores date/time in milliseconds since the epoch. You would like to convert it to an appropriate date type to visualise on Kibana properly. In this case, I would recommend two solutions:

1) If you are able to define a mapping, use the the following for `insert.datePeticio` field:

```
"mappings": {
  "_doc": {
    "properties": {
      "insert.datePeticio": {
        "format": "epoch_millis",
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This allows Kibana to define and represent `insert.datePeticio` field as date even though the actual value is store in miliseconds as integer on Elasticsearch.

2) If not, so cannot make any changes on the original mapping, create a scripted field on Kibana as follows:

- Go to **Management > Index Patterns**
- Select the **Index Pattern** you want to modify
- Select the index pattern’s **Scripted Fields** tab
- Click **Add Scripted Field**
- Fill the form referring to the image below, and Save it.

[image: How to create a scripted field]

If you go to **Kibana > Discover**, you can see two fields together in different representations and types: `insert.datePeticio: 1,546,185,770,733` and `insert.datePeticio_UTC:December 30th 2018, 16:02:50.733`. Since being a date type, the scripted field `insert.datePeticio_UTC` can be easily used to create visualisations based on date aggregations.

> Note: Scripted fields compute data on the fly from the data in your Elasticsearch indices. Keep in mind that computing data on the fly with scripted fields can be very resource intensive and can have a direct impact on Kibana’s performance.

Comment: Sorry that I am asking a question here, but can you do that the other way round? Convert that date to milliseconds?

Comment: FYI: Scripted fields are deprecated now. Use runtime fields instead.